# Charge in a conductor

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge

How to measure net charge flowing through a current-carrying conductor or a wire without actually measuring the current?

Comment: What's the distinction you're making between the "charge flowing" and the current?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to measure the current without breaking the circuit you can use a current clamp or some other inductive measurement method

Comment: @ThePhoton current has time i.e q/t whereas charge is n X e i.e no. of electrons into charge on one electron

Comment: So you want to measure the integral of current over some time period?

Comment: @ThePhoton no. of electrons moving

Comment: Still confused. Do you want to know the number (or density) of mobile carriers in the wire (regardless of whether they're actually moving or not). Or do you want to know how many carriers flowed past some surface cross-sectioning the wire in some period of time?

Comment: @ThePhoton Number of electrons

Comment: Number of electrons what? Number of electrons passing through a surface? Or number of electrons present in the device?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to measure the Hall Effect, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect

This is originally how physicists measured the number of charge carriers for various semiconductors, but the same measurement can be made of conductors.

Comment: I think this requires measuring the potential difference which is a function of current